# Rust Get request with parameters

Tags: rust, actix-web

I have the following asynchronous function within an implementation `#[async_trait]`

```
pub async fn get_field_value(field: web::Path<String>, value: web::Path<String>) -> HttpResponse {
    let json_message = json!({
        "field": field.0,
        "value": value.0
    });
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(json_message)
}
```

now i have my router function

```
pub fn init_router(config: &mut ServiceConfig){
    config.service(web::resource("/get/field-value/{field}/{value}").route(web::get().to(get_field_value)));
}
```

then when running the web application: `localhost:3000/get/field-value/name/James`
I don't get the Json if not I get the following error:

```
wrong number of parameters: 2 expected 1
```

I think I shouldn't get the error because I initialize the value in the parameters correctly.
Neither `#[async_trait]` allows me to use `#[get("/get/field-value/{field}/{value}")]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the route handler is given one argument that contains all values in the route pattern, rather than two separate String arguments. You can use a tuple to get the two values:

```
pub async fn get_field_value(field: web::Path<(String, String)>) -> HttpResponse
```

Or you can use serde to deserialize the fields from the route pattern for you:

```
#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize)]
pub struct Field {
    pub field: String,
    pub value: String,
}

pub async fn get_field_value(data: web::Path<Field>) -> HttpResponse {
    let json_message = json!({
        "field": data.field,
        "value": data.value
    });
    HttpResponse::Ok().json(json_message)
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, it is what I expected.